# Edge computing + server vs server-only solution

Tags: deep-learning, server, artificial-intelligence

Is edge computing for deep learning, really necessary if I need a server to store the info processed in the edge?
For instance, if I have a camera that will capture frames and send to edge computing for processing. After it processes, the frame and other info is sent to a server where a webpage is running. This info will be displayed in the webpage and stored in database. Only after the image and info reaches the server, I can make decisions.

Isn't the edge computer a waste of hardware, since the processing can be done in the server?
If I have multiple cameras, I'll need multiple edge computers.

In one architecture we have a server that receives multiple frames from multiple edge computers (each edge computer is connected to a camera). And in the other we have a server with a good GPU that will process the frames that come from multiple cameras. In this last we don't need edge computing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on your use case. If your app or solution has limited area then it's fine but if you have multiple users around the globe then Edge computing can be useful.

Basically Edge computing as an architecture has a use case to establish delivery network for executable files. If you know CDN(Content Delivery Network) which is widely use to cache or store static assets (i.e. Images, jQuery etc..) in multiple server locations in order to deliver and load assets faster (as it loads from nearer server) hence performance, same way Edge computing allows an app to have their executable files as well as database on multiple server location in order to get better performance for dynamic content

Comment: So, the app is only for one client/user. We can have multiple clients, but each one has their own app. Different clients can't access the same app (same domain). Basically the system is one server per client (user) that can have multiple cameras for surveillance. I noticed I can get frames directly from the camera and process them in the server. I just want to know if in a client/user perspective the edge computing is really necessary. Check my edit for more information.

Comment: So, basically you have 2 server setup. Here is my understanding about your architecture. You have a server setup with different edge computing architecture, like one server is to receive all the frames from different edge computers, then system send those frames from one server to your another server which has good GPU and there system do the process. If it's true then you kept one server only to get frames from edge computers. Correct me if needed.

Comment: Right now we have a server + edge architecture. We have a server where an app is running and that receives frames that are processed in the edge computer. The edge computer, through api, receives a frame from the camera and process it. After processing the frame, the edge computer sends it to the server. My question is, in the client/user perspective, isn't this too much hardware? Wouldn't a solution with a server only enough for the task?